# Modelo de base de datos

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, estructuras-de-datos

Tengo el siguiente modelo de base de datos en 4 tablas. La primera, 
"persona", con los siguientes elementos: id, nombre, apellido, cedula, email. La segunda, llamada "usuario", con id, id_persona, id_departamento, id_sede, nombre, clave, tipo. La tercera, llamada "sede", con id y nombre y la última, llamada "departamento", con id, id_sede y nombre.

[image: duda base de datos]

¿Cuál sería la forma de hacerlo bien, si lo estoy haciendo mal?
Empiezo a hacer el diseño, pero no soy muy bueno como ven.

Mi duda como tal es que si hacerlo así me llevaría menos tiempo de hacer un código para buscar de manera efectiva los datos que ingrese en ella.

Comment: no considero que la tabla usuario este bien identificada con sus atributos, ¿cual es la funcionalidad de dicha tabla?

Comment: contener los datos de acceso tiene mas, como activo , ultimo logueo , fecha modificacion

Comment: entonces no creo q8ue el id_sede sea un dato que deba ir ahi

Comment: Aparte de lo ya dicho, la columna `nombre` en la tabla `usuario` ¿a qué correspondería exactamente?

Comment: a la persona @A.Cedano, yo lo estoy viendo de esa manera.
una persona , esta asociada a un usuario que tiene sus datos , este al ser un usario del sistema la organizacion, se le asigna un departamento que a su vez tiene asociada una sede.

Comment: Si ya hay una columna `nombre` en la tabla `persona` esa columna es redundante en la tabla `usuario`. Podrás obtener el nombre haciendo referencia a la tabla `persona` ... algo parecido a lo que te comentaban sobre `id_sede`.

Comment: ah , pero ese es el nombre de usuario , no su nombre de persona

Comment: Ahh, entendido. También la columna `tipo`... no sé si deba ser un `id`. O sea, no sé si en tu sistema haya posibilidad de manejar una tabla `tipos` aparte. Supongamos, que un usuario pueda ser de dos tipos o algo así...

Comment: de hecho esa columna es para definir que tipo de usuari es el usuario pero eso lo estaba manejando mediante php , para que con un select se pudiera actualizar mediante una funcion un campo de esa tabla y mostrar lo relacionado.

crees que al usar php se pueda tener problemas o es mejor en si tenerlo todo guardado en base de datos ? @A.Cedano

Comment: Eso dependerá de los requerimientos de tu programa. Si por ejemplo un usuario puede ser `Administrador` y puede ser `Editor`. En el modelo actual no tienes forma de indicarlo. Tendrías que sacar la columna `tipo` de la tabla `usuario`; crear una tabla `tipos` y otra tabla que relacione los `usuarios_tipos`
. Si por ejemplo en tu aplicación se requiere saber cuáles usuarios son `Administradores` y `Editores` al mismo tiempo, o cuáles son solamente `Editores`, etc, podrás saberlo con facilidad si montas tu modelo lo más independiente posible. No sé si me explico.

Comment: si, claramente, me creo una tabla nueva para poder mejorar resultados de busqueda .
de verdad , gracias. 
estoy preparando otra pregunta ya .

Answer (score 2):

El principal arreglo que veo necesario en tu modelo de datos es el de tener la columna `id_sede` en la tabla `usuario`.

Según tu modelo de datos, un departamento tiene una serie incluida, por lo que el `usuario` sólo necesita tener el `id_departamento`. Tal cual como está, nada impide que a nivel de base de datos tengas un usuario con un `id_sede` y un `id_departamento` que tiene otra `id_sede`, generando una inconsistencia en los datos.

Comment: cierto coincidimos

Comment: eso era lo que queria confirmar @lamak

Comment: gracias a ti tambien @Shadow Paz